# How to use Expression for Linq union and intersect?

Tags: linq, expression

I have code

```
public static class PredicateExtensions
    {

        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return f => true; }
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return f => false; }

        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression2)
        {
            var invokedExpression = Expression.Invoke(expression2, expression1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Or(expression1.Body, invokedExpression), expression1.Parameters);
        }
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression2)
        {
            var invokedExpression = Expression.Invoke(expression2, expression1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.And(expression1.Body, invokedExpression), expression1.Parameters);
        }
    }
```

How to use this code instead of LINQ Union and Intersect methods ?

Comment: This is the well known predicate builder -- it exists to facilitate composition of `.Where` clauses.  It has nothing to do with either `Union` or `Intersect` -- use those methods as you normally would.

Comment: I was given a hint: "Use something like
`var predicate = PredicateExtensions.False <Customer> ();`
`predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.CustomerID.Contains ("N"))`
Correspondingly, "Union" replaced by "Or" and the "Intersect" at the "And"."

Comment: that hint makes no sense to me.  `Union` and `Intersect` are set operations that operate on a sequence.  PredicateBuilder's `And` and `Or` are boolean operations that operate on predicates.  They really have nothing to do with one another.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a union and intersection of the form:

```
var union = source.Where(predicate0).Union(source.Where(predicate1));
var inter = source.Where(predicate0).Intersect(source.Where(predicate1));
```

Then `union` will have the values for which either `predicate0` or `predicate1` was true while `inter` will have the values for which both `predicate0` and `predicate1` were true.

For this reason, the following would have the same result:

```
var union = source.Where(predicate0.Or(predicate1));
var inter = source.Where(predicate0.And(predicate1));
```

This depends upon the components of the union and intersection being produced by two `Where` queries though. In the likes of:

```
var union = source1.Where(predicate0).Select(item => item.ID)
  .Union(source2.Where(predicate1).Select(item => item.ID));
```

Then it's likely that the predicates aren't even of the same type, and there are yet other cases where combining predicates will not work as a replacement of `Union` and `Intersect`.

It is though useful to be able to consider the first examples both ways, in terms of one's understanding of how predicates, unions and intersections work.